# breadcrumb.phtml file path?

Tags: magento, themes

I am still trying to understand the themeing engine of magento by studying a theme. im my theme there is breadcrumb pthml file in templates/page/html folder which manipulates the bradcrumbs. How does magento know about the file? does the page/html folder is standard.
and what is the role of the

 files do in page.xml

Comment: if u are developing on ubuntu , firebug and grep are your best friends

Comment: How does magento know about the file?

You can find breadcrumbs block inside app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml

`<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>`

Then you can check block class inside app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Breadcrumbs.php , you can find the following line there

`public function __construct()
    {
     parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml');
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template system in magento consists of

```
•   XML layout configuration
•   PHP template files
•   PHP block classes
```

All layout XML files will be found in the `app/design/frontend/<interface>/<theme>/layout` folder.

All template files will be in the .phtml files found in various folders under the `app/design/frontend/<interface>/<theme>/template` folder.

All blocks will be in the `app/code/<core,local,community>/<namespace>/<module>/Block` folder.

You may not find all the layout/template files in same theme say telescope. For example, Magento will check the following folders, in order, for a file named catalog.xml:

```
    app/design/frontend/interface/telescope/layout/
    app/design/frontend/interface/default/layout/
    app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/
```

Answer (score 1):

Breadcrumbs template file will be under your current theme.

for example:

```
app/design/frontend/<pkg>/<theme>/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

If its not present in current theme then it will be in base theme

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

Magento template engine first looks block/page template in active theme if not found the will look in base theme.

Answer (score 0):

this is handled by layout handlers and block descriptions so if you are new in business head to magento knowledgebase and read theming tutorials there

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml:82: <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

Comment: this means <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header"> this block can be modified by putting header.phtml file in page/html/ folder and i can create new blocks also . for eg. <block type="page/html_header" name="headertop" as="headertop" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"> by putting this line in page.xml